# (Python): O(logn) running time for duplicate item in a sorted list

Tags: python, performance, duplicates

Here is my code so far:

```
def find_duplicate(L):
    low = 0
    high = len(L)-1
    mid = 0
    midval = 0
    while low <= high:
        mid = (low + high )// 2
        midval = L[mid]
        
        if midval == mid:
            low = mid + 1
        else:
            high = mid - 1
    return high
```

which only seems to return the correct value *if* the list starts at 0.
What can I do to make it so it can find the duplicate of **any** sorted list?

Comment: Could you provide the value of ```L``` too?

Comment: L can be any sorted list. ex: [44, 49, 50, 51, 53, 53, 59]

Comment: Are you trying to find ```mid``` value from the list or ```high``` value? What value the output supposed to print?

Comment: What do you mean by ```duplicate```? What is the expected correct output?